# Should SELinux be enabled and the filesystem relabelled before or after other software has been installed?

Tags: selinux

I have an AlmaLinux 9 server with SELinux installed but currently disabled as the server isn't in production use yet.

I am ready to start installing other applications (e.g. Apache, PHP, Postfix, Logwatch, Fail2ban, etc.) but what I would like to know is whether I should set SELinux to enforcing and relabel the file system *before* I install these applications or wait until I've installed all the software I need and do it then? Does it make any difference?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions/comments.

Comment: Depends on when you want to see what breaks.

Comment: Yes, I get that. What I'm really trying to find out is whether I need to keep relabelling the filesystem and re-enabling SELinux after I install new applications because the security context that existed when SELinux was enabled would change whenever I install a new application. I usually "wing it" with SELinux and just deal with errors as they appear but I'd like to know what the correct approach is.

Comment: why should a security context change when an application is installed? Installing a package will add new files and folders which may or may not have contextes that weren't there before, but it won't change the context of existing files and folders.

Comment: My understanding was that when SELinux was enabled and the file system relabelled it would set certain permissions or restrictions on files so that they can't be modified. So, if you install an application after you've enabled SELinux and relabelled the file system, the files and services associated with the new application haven't been processed. Therefore, the new application isn't necessarily secured as might be expected.

Comment: Sorry, but that "understanding" is complete gibberish. Usually you don't need to relabel the filesystem of SELinux enabled machines at all.

Comment: In the Red Hat documentation it says "You may never need to relabel an entire file system. This usually occurs only when labeling a file system for SELinux for the first time, or when switching between different types of policy, such as changing from the targeted to the strict policy." Which is what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you totally disable selinux, then you have to relabel the filesystem when re-enabling it as any new content will not have a selinux context (ie: what you can see via `ls -Z`).

But disabling selinux is almost never the right approach. If having issue and/or for debugging purpose, you should put it into `permissive` mode. In this mode selinux will permit basically any operation, but will log policy violation. You can examine the log file and see if any issue with selinux exists. When you are confident enough, you can put selinux into `enforcing` mode.

However, I generally restrict `permissive` use to debug session only - I prefer to have the system into `enforcing` mode as soon as possible (ie: at installation time) and progressively deal with the eventual fallout, rather than concurrently debugging multiple blocking issues at a later time (when switching from `permissive` to `enforcing`).

Comment: So just to confirm, if I enable SELinux now and then install new applications afterwards, does the filesystem have to be relabelled again?  I do intend to run SELinux in enforcing mode.

Comment: No, when selinux is enabled (both in `permissive` and `enforcing` modes) you don't have to relabel the filesystem.